# Not able to print the exact program like ls error in C

Tags: c, unix

I created my own shell and trying to redirect the STDERR to output file.

I did :

```
dup2(output_fd, 2);
```

and when I am executing child, I am using

```
error_message = strerror(errno);
 write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
```

but the problem is I am getting this error message only :

No such file or directory

whereas I should be getting

```
ls: cannot access '/no/such/file': No such file or directory
```

running program : ls /no/such/file > output

Comment: [strerror](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) returns the generic error string for that error number.

Comment: `whereas I should be getting` No, you should be getting only "No such file or directory". It's `ls` (the program) that is printing the other stuff. `ls` is doing like `fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot access '%s': %s\n", program_name, file_path, strerror(errno));`

Answer (score 0):

`ls` is printing the message `ls: cannot access 'stuff':` by itself - in [ls.c file_failure(... "cannot access") call](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L3425) and [file_failure() definition](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L2868) and [error() is a standard function from error.h](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/error.3.html). There's even no `strerror` call in `ls` sources - [error() in glibc sources](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/error.c#L187) calls it.

So write the message yourself, use `fprintf(stderr` to format your message, or you may use GNU extension `erorr()` if you want.

`strerror` should return just `"No such file or directory"` and this is **the** standard message from `strerror` for `ENOENT`. There is [`errno -l`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/errno/) to list errors with strings in terminal and [here is list of errors in glibc sources](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/gnu/errlist.c.html#83).